# Xcode status bar hidden - different on iPad and iPhone

Tags: xcode, hidden, statusbar

Of course I know how to change the status bar — [application setStatusBar...] — once the application has been loaded in the application:applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method.

But I'm working on the universal application (using window based app template) and I've only one [projectName]-Info.plist.

There is only one key "Status bar is initially hidden" that can be added to above plist file, and there is no variant for iPhone and iPad (like for supported device orientation).

So is there any way to show initially the status bar on iPad, and to have it hidden on iPhone?
Browsing neither Stack Overflow nor Apple docs gave me the answer.

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question yet? Have just run into the same issue!